# How can I keep Windows Vista from updating Internet Explorer 7?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, windows-update, internet-explorer-7

I have Windows Vista installed in a VirtualBox VM so that I can test websites in Internet Explorer 7.

I am embarrassed to say I don't have much of an idea how Windows Update works (Linux user for many years), so I was wondering if there is any way I can make it *NOT* update Internet Explorer 7.

I know I can turn off updates, but would rather not completely turn off updates if I don't have to.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14149 might help, but not too many people are going to be using IE7 soon: http://www.scmagazineuk.com/microsoft-announces-plans-to-silently-update-internet-explorer/article/219675/

Comment: @todda.speot.is: Unfortunally you are wrong, many people (mostly in industrial environment) use very old hard- and software including IE7, IE6 and even older versions.

Comment: @MichaelK - Good things those computers have no business being connected to the internet.  Microsoft plans to update copies of IE7 and IE8 to IE9.  Darkmok, do everyone a favor, do not support IE6/IE7 they are not secure.

Comment: I wish that those computers are not connected to the internet, but importunately some of the are. I worked in company for some time that used IE6 as their standard browser and floppy disks instead of USB sticks... that was 2 years ago.

Comment: @Ramhound  - If it were my choice I would not support ANY version of IE :)  Sadly, the site is used by "enterprisey" users, and believe it or not, a large percentage are still using IE7. Some are even using IE6 !

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to stop the IE7 from updating is to disable all updates, or set them to "only notify me" and select the updates you want on your own like shown here: [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Turn-automatic-updating-on-or-off).

Answer (score 0):

Set registry keys to stop installations of IE8 and IE9 as follows:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Setup\8.0, key DoNotAllowIE80
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Setup\9.0, key DoNotAllowIE90
```

- When the key value name is not defined, distribution is not blocked.
- When the key value name is set to 0, distribution is not blocked.
- When the key value name is set to 1, distribution is blocked.

[IE8 blocker tool kit download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14149)
[IE9 blocker tool kit download](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=179)

Answer (score 0):

Open Windows Update and find the update that will install Internet Explorer 8. Right click on it and say "hide this update". This way it will not install Internet Explorer 8 until you manually unhide it again.